# How to use the XOR "^" on two strings

Tags: javascript

I have two strings:

```
var temp1 = "6219000041889600";
var temp2 = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
```

I would like to XOR these two, however I know that in JavaScript you cannot XOR string and can only for int.

So Is there a way to do this? I know for the first value i can use:

```
var temp1_A= parseInt(temp1); //equal to 6219000041889600
```

However

```
var temp1_B= parseInt(temp12,16) // yields 1152921504606847000
```

Then performing `temp1_A ^ temp1_B` yields `1159140504648736600` (but this is decimal) and converting back to HEX is `10161825C85ADF58` which is not my desired result.

It should be (when both hex according to [Here](http://xor.pw/?))

```
6219000041889600 ^ FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = 9DE6FFFFBE7769FF`
```

but how would I go about XOR'ing this value with 8-bytes of FF.

Comment: JavaScript's binary operators currently only support up to 32-bit integers (4 bytes). To exceed that, you'll have to process the strings in segments that fit under that limit and concatenate the results.

Comment: You'll need to either look for a BigInt implementation, or parse those hex strings to arrays of 32-bit ints and do the operation manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've left the bounds of the 31-bit integer precision in JavaScript. You'll need to process your strings in chunks:

```
function XOR_hex(a, b) {
    var res = "",
        l = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    for (var i=0; i<l; i+=4)
        res = ("000"+(parseInt(a.slice(-i-4, -i||a.length), 16) ^ parseInt(b.slice(-i-4, -i||b.length), 16)).toString(16)).slice(-4) + res;
    return res;
}
```

or maybe easier char-by-char:

```
function XOR_hex(a, b) {
    var res = "",
        i = a.length,
        j = b.length;
    while (i-->0 && j-->0)
        res = (parseInt(a.charAt(i), 16) ^ parseInt(b.charAt(j), 16)).toString(16) + res;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Perfect the second one works amazingly. Thanks you so much for the help!